# Get final result from data table

Tags: c#, datatable

I am creating a datatable with 3 columns as below and pushing the values into it from a while loop. Once the while loop is completed. I want to extract the validation values which are True or False and apply a condition to that, **which will be like if all the values are "True" then I should get an output "True" if anyone of them is "False" I should get "False" value as output.**

```
DataTable table = new DataTable(); table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int)); 
table.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Validation", typeof(string));
```

For getting values of column Validation I am using the code below, but not sure how to apply the above condition and get final value.

```
DataView dv = new DataView(table);
DataTable dt = dv.ToTable(true, "Validation");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used and the above issue was resolved. Added the reference for System.Data.DataSetExtensions.

```
string validationstr = "False";
bool Contains = table.AsEnumerable().Any(row => validationstr == row.Field<string>("Validation"));
if (Contains == true)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to iterate the datatable and check the value of each row.

```
foreach (DataRow dtRow in dtTable.Rows)
{
    // On all tables' columns
    foreach(DataColumn dc in dtTable.Columns)
    {
      var field1 = dtRow[dc].ToString();
    }
}
```